# Calling api manually in `useEffect()`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have question about `useEffect()` of function component.

This script calls api from server and shows the contents.

```
const NameList = (props) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    var url =  `http://localhost/blogs`;
    axios.get(url)
    .then((res)=> {
    setResult(res.data.items);
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
  }, []);
  return(  
    <TableBody>
    {
      result.map(item => {
        return (
          <TableRow key={item.id}>
          <TableCell>
          {item.name}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        )
      })
    }
    </TableBody>  
  );
}
```

It shows the list when page is loaded(it's great and `useEffect` is useful).

and I want to call api by manually to refresh the list (ex. when button is clicked in another component, etc.)

I have two ideas.

A) Keeping `ajax(axios.get)` in `useEffect()` and call `useEffect()` from button somehow.

B) Making new function including `ajax` outside of `useEffect()` and call this from both button and `useEffect()`.

I might still confuse of how to use `useEffect()`.

I appreciate the advice which one is the best practice and how can I make it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new state variable eg. refresh.

```
 const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
```

update the refresh variable, whenever you want the useEffect to be called, eg inside of your onClick handler

```
  setRefresh(!refresh);
```

add refresh to the useEffect dependancy array, on the last line of use effect

```
 }, [refresh]);
```

now useEffect gets called on 1st render like now, and everytime refresh state variable changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have use class components before, useEffect is the combination of the lifecycle methods: componentDidMount(), componentDidUpdate() and componentWillUnmount().  If there isn't any tracked states in the tracked array, useEffect only fires when the component is mounted for the first time, which achieve the same effect as componentDidMount().

So option B is good, define the function outside, and use it in useEffect when it mounted the first time:

```
function getData() {
    var url =  `http://localhost/blogs`;
    axios.get(url)
    .then((res)=> {
    setResult(res.data.items);
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
}

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
},[])
```

And then use a separate button to trigger the function:

```
<button onClick={getData}>Get Data</button
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you wish to take data on reload, **useEffect** will already take care of it, and if you are adding a custom button, it is advised to have a separate function that returns a promise, and then you can easily place it in the **useEffect** function and wait for it, also reduce redundancy, And this is more efficient

```js
...
// to get the data incase of conditions where we only need data and state change is not required
function functionName(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        var url =  `http://localhost/blogs`;
        axios.get(url)
        .then((res)=> {
        resolve(res.data.items);
        })
        .catch(err=>{reject(err);});
    })
}
// to handle the refresh button click, 
// wire the function below to any button onClick so that refresh process will be done.
function manualRefreshOperation(){
    functionName()
    .then((res)=> {
    setResult(res);
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err);});
}

useEffect(() => {
    manualRefreshOperation();
  }, []);
```

This process can help reduce the redundancy, and also makes sure you can link it to any function

Answer (score 0):

You can't manually call useEffect. Go with option B. Define the ajax call in a separate function and then call this function both in useEffect and in your button's onClick callback. The only other thing you could do is if the state changes when the user clicks on the button, then you could put that state variable into the dependency array of useEffect since it will be called when the component mounts and when that state variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

> B) Making new function including ajax outside of useEffect() and call this from both button and useEffect().

This is a good idea. You can abstract your data fetching code into a function that you can call both in your effect, and elsewhere (in another event handler for example).

Here I've attached it to a click handler on a refresh button.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

var url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character`;

const NameList = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
  const [error, seterror] = useState("");
  
  const fetchData = () => {
    setloading(true);

    // get 3 random characters
    const characters = [...Array(3)].map(() => (Math.random() * 183) | 0);
    axios
      .get(`${url}/${characters}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setResult(res.data);
        seterror("");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        seterror(err.message);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setloading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => fetchData()}>refresh</button>
      {error ? (
        <p>{error}</p>
      ) : loading ? (
        <p>"loading..."</p>
      ) : (
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {result.map((item) => {
              return (
                <tr key={item.id}>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default NameList;
```

[image: Edit brave-dijkstra-tkoy3]